# What happens when a contract was signed but a party can't fullfill their obligations due to circumstances outside their control (COVID)

Tags: contract-law

I signed a contract with a venue for a 150 person wedding.  Due to COVID, that is now impossible and illegal in the state of California.  Being that the venue cannot guarantee that we could proceed with a 150 person wedding, can that contract be void?

Answer (score -1):

This will depend on the exact provisions of the contract. If the contract does not specify what happens if factors beyond the parties' control prevent the fulfillment of the contract, the deal will be undone to the extent possible -- that is the vendor will be released from obligations but will have to return any payments. However, if the vendor has incurred good-faith expenses, it may be entitled to payment for them.

If the contrast specifies what happens in such an event, its provisions will be followed unless they contradict law or public policy.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong

Comment: @Dale M I am not infallible, but would you care to indicate where I am wrong, and give any hint as to what would be correct?

Comment: see the question this is a dup of

Comment: @Colin If you mean Dale M., he is a **very** experienced poster here who does not troll. Our answers disagree largely on the default case : what happens when the contract does not specify a result. Note that *force majeure* does not apply by default in most common-law jurisdictions. In fact "trolliing" is hostile and I ask you to retract it.

Comment: "Ttolling" in an online forum means that a person is not  being sincere or honest, but is raising points only to start an argument, or to annoy the other parties. It is about as serious an accusation as can be made in such a forum. A troll often moves goal posts, or raises irrelevant side issues, just to keep the argument hoping. *Force majeure* is too big to handle further in a comment and I need to check sources.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yeah I mean, I do kind of think Dale can't be being sincere or honest when saying that your answer is "completely wrong." He might honestly think it's incomplete, but your answer is certainly 95% correct.

Comment: @DavidSiegel when you research that issue, you'll come across different terms: *force majeure*, impossibility, impracticability, frustration of purpose. Different jurisdictions will define them differently. But, they all revolve around the same general idea: if you contract with me to paint your house, and it burns down, I don't have to perform, OTOH, if a contract has just turned out to be a bad bet for one side, that doesn't relieve them of their obligation. Everything else is shades of grey in between.